# Rest API method is returning value but still receive 500 error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, jersey

I'm working on a Java Jersey REST API and a website using this API.

This is my server side method

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TreeViewModel> getTreeList() {
    User user = User.getByCredentials("team", "team");
    List<TreeViewModel> list = user.getTreeViewModels();
    return list;
}
```

And this is my javascript request

```
function requestTrees() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: window.api + "tree",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth('team', 'team'));
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('suc');
    },
    complete: function(jqxhr, txt_status) {
        console.log('com');
    },
    failed: function(data) {
        console.log('fai');
    }
});
```

}

If I debug my server the method gets called and returns the list. But at client side I receive a 500 error which indicates something is wrong at server side?

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your console output. You may have a problem while serializing the object to a JSON `String`.

Comment: What does your server debug output say? Or better yet put a breakpoint on it. My guess is that your JSON generator cannot create a JSON representation of the TreeViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 means internal server error, and should usually be accompanied by log messages or even in some cases an exception embedded in the message body sent to the client.

What has most likely happened is that your method has processed and returned the `List<TreeViewModel>` but that could not then be serialized for sending.

For example some serializers do not like working with raw collections. You need to have your own object and then put the list within that. The only way to find the actual cause of the problem though is to find that exception and see what it is telling you.